# What the value of x within lambda in `Enumerable.All` when the List is empty?

Tags: c#

Let's say there's a function that generates prime numbers:

```
static void Main() {
    var n = 10;

    var primeNumbers = new List<int>();
    int current = 2;


    // Console.WriteLine(primeNumbers.All((x) => current % x != 0));
    while (primeNumbers.Count <= n) {
        if (primeNumbers.All((x) => current % x != 0)) {
            primeNumbers.Add(current);
            Console.WriteLine("Prime number: " + current);
        }

        current++;
    }
}
```

On the very first iteration within `while` the list is empty. Why method `Enumerable.All` gives back `True` (all elements of a sequence satisfy a condition which is `current % x != 0`). What the value of `x`?

Comment: There aren't any elements which _don't_ satisfy the predicate...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason why you get `true` is provided by the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb548541%28v=vs.100%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396):

> `true` if every element of the source sequence passes the test in the specified predicate, or if the sequence is empty; otherwise, `false`.

This makes sense logically, too, because `All` is supposed to mean the same thing as `!Any(...)`. Since `Any` would evaluate to `false` for an empty collection, it follows that `All` should evaluate to `true` under the same circumstances.

Comment: I know that. But there's the expression `current % x != 0` which is on the first iteration becoming `2 % x != 0`. In order to add the first element into the list and increase the `current` it have to pass `if` statement. But neither `2 % 1` or ` `2 % 0` `!= 0`.

Comment: @J.Doe - If the list is empty the lambda is never called so `x` is never bound to anything. `All` can return true immediately without invoking the predicate.